# Need SQL query for a quiz application

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application with forty questions. I'm holding the questions in tbQuestion and their corresponding answers in tbAnswer along with what answer the user chose in tbResult.

Here's the table structure:

```
tbQuestion:      tbAnswer:        tbResult:
QuestionID       AnswerID         ResultID
QuestionText     QuestionID       QuestionID
                 AnswerText       AnswerID
                                  UserID
```

I want to select all the questions but indicate whether they've been answered or not by if there is a row in tbResult. It's something along the lines of the below query but It's only selecting questions I have answered. I want to use AS Answered as an indicator of whether it's been answered. Blank if it's not answered, the AnswerID if it has been answered.

```
SELECT tbQuestion.QuestionID, QuestionText, tbAnswer.AnswerID, AnswerText, tbResult.AnseredID AS Answered
FROM tbQuestion
JOIN tbAnswer ON tbQuestion.QuestionID = tbAnswer.QuestionID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbResult ON tbQuestion.QuestionID = tbResult.QuestionID
WHERE  tbResult.UserID = 1234567
```

Also there are 39 radio input answers (one answer per question) and 1 question with checkboxes where the user can have multiple answers for one question so I'll have to know the AnswerID of of each answer they gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the condition in your WHERE clause to the ON clause of the outer join:

```
select q.questionid,
       q.questiontext,
       a.answerid,
       a.answertext,
       r.anseredid as answered
  from tbquestion q
  join tbanswer a
    on q.questionid = a.questionid
  left join tbresult r
    on q.questionid = r.questionid
   and r.userid = 1234567 -- moved to on clause
```

Right now your query is only showing questions actually answered by the user, because your criteria specifying the user is in the WHERE clause. If the user never fills out an answer for a given question they won't have a row on tbresult (for the given question) so the row will be null. In order to allow nulls, you place such criteria into the on clause of an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Try just LEFT OUTER JOIN tbAnswer

```
SELECT  tbQuestion.QuestionID ,
    QuestionText ,
    tbAnswer.AnswerID ,
    AnswerText ,
    tbResult.AnseredID AS Answered
 FROM    tbQuestion
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbAnswer
        ON tbQuestion.QuestionID = tbAnswer.QuestionID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbResult
        ON tbQuestion.QuestionID = tbResult.QuestionID
WHERE   tbResult.UserID = 1234567
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT tbQuestion.QuestionID, QuestionText, tbAnswer.AnswerID, AnswerText, 
       case when 
           tbResult.ResultId is null 
              then convert(bit, 0) 
              else convert(bit, 1) 
       END AS Answered
FROM tbQuestion
JOIN tbAnswer ON tbQuestion.QuestionID = tbAnswer.QuestionID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbResult ON tbQuestion.QuestionID = tbResult.QuestionID
    and tbAnswer.AnswerId = tbResult.AnswerId
    and tbResult.UserID = 1234567
```

to get most of the answer to your question.
 when you have multiple results (for your multiple choice) how do you want that result to be displayed since it'll be multiple resultIds to a single question?